# How to look up other people's Google Custom Searches

Tags: google-custom-search

When I attempt to use someone else's custom search by its url, I get taken instead to my own custom search admin page.

How do I use someone else's custom search url?

For example, customsearchengine.com has an entry for the [OpenDOAR search](https://www.customsearchengine.com/detail.php?id=70).

It gives the url as: http://www.google.com/coop/cse?cx=016766439200934687091:ln-icm1qyko

When I put this in, I get redirected to https://cse.google.com/cse/all

Perhaps that custom search doesn't exist anymore. Bu the same happens when I try to look up other custom searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.customsearchengine.com/ is super old, and not affiliated with google.

Custom Search's URL format has changed since 2008, so instead of
 http://www.google.com/coop/cse?cx=016766439200934687091:ln-icm1qyko
you can use
http://www.google.com/cse?cx=016766439200934687091:ln-icm1qyko

but that CSE doesn't exist any longer, so 404 error

Comment: In addition, a response from Google (Google Custom Search folk seem very responsive to feedback). They say, if user's custom search has a public URL, it has the form: `https://cse.google.com/cse?cx=<Search Engine ID>`